# LUA curl request with timeout

Tags: curl, lua

I use the LUA-code for sending json-data to backend:

```
local cURL = require("cURL")
local c, err = cURL.easy{
  url = "http://10.10.10.10",
  post = true,
  httpheader = { "Content-Type: application/json"; },
  postfields = jsonString
}

local ok, err = c:perform()
```

Everything works perfect except one thing. If I don't receive response from the server, my script continue working. I need to add some timeout and if during timeout I don't receive response, close connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [documentation](http://lua-curl.github.io/lcurl/modules/lcurl.html#easy) `easy` creates an Easy object that receives an options table as a parameter:

```
 c = curl.easy{
   url = 'http://example.com',
   [curl.OPT_VERBOSE] = true,
 }
```

Now I think that in the same way you can pass the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` [parameter](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html) which sets the maximum time the request is allowed to take. So in code:

```
local c, err = cURL.easy{
  url = "http://10.10.10.10",
  post = true,
  httpheader = { "Content-Type: application/json"; },
  postfields = jsonString,
  [curl.OPT_TIMEOUT] = 60, --Your timeout of choice
}
```

Again, I hadn't had to actually use this parameter before but I'm confident that this works the same manner as other `CURLOPT` parameters.

Comment: Maybe wrap it in `assert()` and issue a message when it returns nil?

Comment: For handling timeout error: `local ok, err = pcall(function() c:perform() end)`

Comment: Just use `cURL.safe` module which return error object as second return value. Also, instead of `[curl.OPT_TIMEOUT] = 60` you can just write `timeout = 60`